# every time I click run on my delphi project it says couldn't find .exe but everything is already coded

Tags: delphi

Is there a way to make an .exe file after you coded?, because I did a project in Delphi and tried to run it but it says couldn't find .exe file.

Comment: 10.3.3 don't know how to add the .Dpr file

Comment: Can you try to create a new project and run that?

Comment: Might be caused by your antivirus software.

Comment: After you have coded you have to compile / build that code. That is done with either ``F9`` or ``Shift + F9`` (full build).

Comment: What happens if you try to run one of the sample projecrs that come with Delphi?